# Como enviar datos cada cierto tiempo con Ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

Buen dia. Amigos otras vez molestandolos. Mira tengo este codigo que cada 10 segundo hace una consulta a un codigo que esta en la otra pagina. pero quiero saber como enviar  los datos de los input en ese mismo tiempo a la pagina respuestachat.php

```
<?php
     //verifico si la persona a ingresado el correo en esta //parte para poder que se llenen las variables de los input
    if(isset($_POST["comprador"])) { // Se pasa una acción
        switch(sprintf("%d", $_POST["comprador"])) { // ¿Qué acción?
            case 1:
                update(); // Llamar a tu función
                echo "Tarea completada!";
                break;
            default:
                echo "Error: Falta una acción";
        }
    }

    function update() {
        
        
    }
?>
```

estos son los input que quiero enviar cada diez segundo que la funciona haga la consulta.

">

```
 <input  type="text" id="comprador" name="comprador" value="<?php echo$Comprador?>">

<input type="text" id="correovendedor" name="correovendedor" value="<?php echo$correovendedor?>">


<script>
    $(function() { // Ojo! uso jQuery, recuerda añadirla al html
        cron(); // Lanzo cron la primera vez
        function cron() {
             
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "respuestachat.php", // Podrías separar las funciones de PHP en un fichero a parte
                data: {

                    action: 1
                }

            })
            .done(function(res){
            $('#respuesta').html(res)   
         })



                      }
        setInterval(function() {
            cron();
        }, 10000); // Lanzará la petición cada 10 segundos
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Saludos. No haces referencia a que comportamiento es del que requieres apoyo (falla, error, no lo hace, etc...); por tu código en la parte **script** veo tienes llamado a **cron();** al inicio; pero eso esta antes de la función del mismo nombre; si te marca algo como que **cron** no existe/definida/.. cambia el orden; primero la función y luego invocarla (el setInterval no debe afectar donde actualmente lo ubicsate).

Comment: En realidad quiero pasar los datos de los input  en esa misma funcion y no se como hacerlo. alli estan los input porque yo se enviar esos datos con ajax. pero dentro de esta función no se como se ubicarian. Le agredezco si me puedes apoyar.

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero lo siguiente:

```
<!-- Tu html (los inputs) sin cambios -->
<input  type="text" id="comprador" name="comprador" value="<?php echo$Comprador?>">

<input type="text" id="correovendedor" name="correovendedor" value="<?php echo$correovendedor?>">
```

```
/*

A continuación llamo a cada variable que se pasa anteponiendo "p" 
y primer letra mayúscula acorde al "id" del input referido, 
este nombre desde luego "es el esperado" en tu "respuestachat.php" allí pones
el que corresponda.

*/
$.ajax(
{
   method: "POST",
   url: "respuestachat.php", // Podrías separar las funciones de PHP en un fichero a parte
   data: {
      action: 1,
      pComprador : $("#comprador").val(),
      pCorreovendedor: $("#correovendedor").val()
   }
}
)
.done(function (res) {
 // Lo que necesites hacer con la respuesta
});


/*
La parte del data del ajax en ocasiones me falla; en ocasiones requiero ponerlo como 
   data: 
      JSON.stringify({
      action: 1,
      pComprador : $("#comprador").val(),
      pCorreovendedor: $("#correovendedor").val()
   })
*/
```

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

simplemente añade los valores a tu objeto `data` de la siguiente manera

```
data: {
   action: 1,
   comprador: $('input#comprador').val(),
   correovendedor: $('input#correovendedor').val()
}
```